# How to test activeadmin AuthorizationAdapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, activeadmin

I have a custom [AutorizationAdapter](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html) that I would like to test using RSpec:

```
class AdminAuthorization < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(_action, _subject = nil)
    user.admin?
  end
end
```

Initially I used a custom method but since I'm using Devise, using a custom AuthorizationAdapter seemed to be the way to go.

How would you go about testing it ? I tought one way to test it is to create a request spec for one of the controller and test for status code & redirection, something like that:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'AdminUsers', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /admin_users' do

    context 'admin' do
      let(:admin_user) { create(:admin_user) }
      before { sign_in super_user }
      get admin_users_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    context 'non admin' do
      let(:user) { create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }
      it 'redirects to the login page' do
        get admin_users_path
        expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
        expect(response).to redirected_to '/admin/login'
      end
    end

    context 'non logged in user' do
      it 'redirects to the login page' do
        get admin_users_path
        expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
        expect(response).to redirected_to '/admin/login'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

These look reasonable to me.  You can also look at the unit and feature specs that are in the ActiveAdmin test suite.  However, AuthorizationAdapter itself is a PORO so you should be able to unit test in isolation: in the example given above that would be a fairly trivial test.